# C Web Server and Chrome Dev tools question

Tags: c++, c, http, sockets

I recently starting diving into http programming in C and have a functioning server that can handle GET and POST.  My question comes in to my site load times and how I should send the response headers and response message.

I notice in Chromes resource tracking tool that there is almost no (a few ms) connecting/sending/proxy/blocking/waiting time in most cases (on the same network as the server), but the receive time can vary wildly.  I'm not entirely sure what the receive time is including. I mostly see a long receive (40 to 140ms or more) time on the png files and sometimes javascript files and rarely other files, but it's not really consistent.

Could anyone shed some light on this for me?

I haven't done much testing yet, but I was wondering if I changed the method which I use to send the header/message would help.  I currently have every file for the site cached in server memory along with it's header (all in the same char*).  When I send the file that was requested, I just do 1 send() call with the header/file combo (it does not involve any string operations b/c it is all done in advance on server start up).

Would it be better to break it into multiple small send() calls?

Just some stats that I get with Chrome dev tools (again, on local network through a wireless router connection), the site loads in from 120ms to 570ms. It's 19 files at a total of 139.85KB.  The computer it's on is a Asus 901 netbook (atom 1.6ghz, 2gb ddr2) with TinyCore linux.  I know there are some optimizations I could be doing with how threads start up and a few other things, but not sure that's affecting it to much atm.

Comment: Have you added any profiling or debug output information to your webserver? It might be useful to add some high resolution timing information inbetween "major" operations in the code so you can see the progression of the request-response cycle from the server side.

Comment: I don't have any profiling at the moment, and minimal debugging (been removing/adding it as needed).  Been relying heavily on chrome dev tools, probably to heavily.  I'm really running blind in the area of what I should be looking for in the speed of a good site delivery/load time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending the entire response in one `send()`, you should set the `TCP_NODELAY` socket option.

If that doesn't help, you may want to try using a packet capturing tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see if you can spot where the delay is introduced.

Comment: I do set the TCP_NODELAY flag, I will see what Wireshark can tell me, thanks for the tip.